# Composition of functions - rules

Tags: calculus

We have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $f \circ g = g \circ f \space (= id)$. Can we then state:

$ f \circ \dfrac{g}{n} = g \circ \dfrac{f}{n} = \dfrac{f}{n} \circ g = \dfrac{g}{n} \circ f$?

Just from fiddling around with some examples (like $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x) = x-1$), I have found that $ f \circ \dfrac{g}{n} = g \circ \dfrac{f}{n}$ is probably true, but that $ g \circ \dfrac{f}{n} \neq \dfrac{f}{n} \circ g$, but I'm not sure if I defined $\dfrac{f}{n} \circ g$ to be fair.

edit: I've thought about it some more and I think the question can effectively be restated as: Is $\dfrac{f}{n} \circ g$ by definition simply $\dfrac{f \circ g}{n}$ or not? Because if it is I think the equality holds for $ n \neq 0$

Comment: Your example isn't very helpful. You have chosen the same function ($x\mapsto x+1$) for $f$ and $g$, so of course they commute under composition. What is $\frac fn$? Does that mean the map $x\mapsto \frac 1n \cdot f(x)$?

Comment: @MPW Was a typo, changed the sign

Comment: @MPW I admittedly haven't defined it all too well, but is there an interpretation for $\dfrac{f}{n} for which the equality in my question holds? Because, just from using algebra (which I admit isn't always possible, hence the question), I'd expect the equality to be true.

Comment: What are *you* defining $f/n$ to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with something non-linear.  Say $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \sqrt(x)$

$g(\frac{f(x)}{2}) = g(\frac{x^2}{2}) = \frac{x}{\sqrt(2)}$

$f(\frac{g(x)}{2})= f(\frac{\sqrt(x)}{2}) = \frac{x}{4}$